# Can I ask any philosophical reason for using (or not using) enum in Typescript (and string union type)

Tags: typescript, types, enums, constants, union

These days I learned the concept of `enum` and `const enum` in Typescript and I got confused. I understood that `const enum` will be transpiled into simple values while the other not. I also understood that some feature differences between using string union type and plain `enum` (like iteration).

But I can't comprehend **when and why** I should (not) use (`const`) `enum`. I think iteration on `enum` is not that general, and it's hard to predict whether they'll use it or not.

There is a post (which is written in Korean so sorry for that) that "tree-shaking cannot optimize transpiled `enum` since they are IIFE". ([Link](https://engineering.linecorp.com/ko/blog/typescript-enum-tree-shaking/))

Than should I just use `const enum` without any hesitation, or is there any more pros and cons using the other alternative: string union type.

TLDR

1. If `const enum` is more lightweighted than `enum`, is there any practical reason to use `enum`?
2. I already know `Babel` can't work with `const enum`. In that case, why someone uses `enum` rather than string union type even if they don't iterate over it.

Comment: `const enums` won't be transpiled to Javascript. So `const enums` are made mainly to use enums as types. On the other side, `enums` are ported to Javascript and can be used as values. If you go to Typescript Playground, you can see how enums get transpiled to Javascript

Comment: Other than the [handbook page about enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums), I don't know there can be an authoritative answer to this question.  It seems like primarily a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `enums` camed to TypeScript from `C#`.
In general numerical `enums` in TypeScript are unsafe. Consider this example:

```js
const enum Foo{
  a,
  b
}

const handle=(arg:Foo)=>arg

handle(42) // no error
```

This is because TypeScript has structural type system and not nominal.

Non `const enum` produces a lot of boilerplate code:

```js
var Foo;
(function (Foo) {
    Foo[Foo["a"] = 0] = "a";
    Foo[Foo["b"] = 1] = "b";
})(Foo || (Foo = {}));
```

So, mi advice is to avoid `enums` at all. You can use immutable object instead. COnsider this example:

```js
const Foo = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
} as const;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Foo = Values<typeof Foo>;

const handle = (arg: Foo) => arg

handle(Foo.a) // ok
handle(Foo.b) // ok

handle(42) // error
```

As for `string unions`, imagine this case:

```js
enum Events {
  click = 'click',
  hover = 'hover'
}

type Union = 'click' | 'hover'
```

you are using `Events.click` as a value in 100 files and then your tech leader saying you that you should rename `click` to `_click`.
You do next:

```js
enum Events {
  click = '_click',
  hover = '_hover'
}
```

and that's it. You need to make a change in only one type declaration whereas in case of union strings you need to replace each using of literal string. This is only one case. I believe there a lot use cases for union string. Assume you have some type where you need to use string literal. There is no reason to create a runtime value only to represent a type. This is the valid case for using string literal instead of `enums`.

It all depends.